# Why did no one want to treat Kili's wound after Thorin left for the Lonely Mountain?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, the-desolation-of-smaug

In the movie "The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug", when Thorin & Company leave from Esgaroth to Erebor by boat, the whole city is cheering them. Shortly after, Kili (who is wounded and was ordered to stay behind by Thorin), Fili, Oin and Bofur knock on Bard's door asking him to help them (with Kili's wound). Bofur mentions that no one will help them.

That seems odd and not very credible to me after just watching the whole city displaying their support for them. They got armour, weapons and food but no one will treat an injured dwarf? Note that Bofur specifically says no one *will* help them and not that no one *can* help them (e.g. due to lacking knowledge in wound treatment). And why do they go to Bard in the first place? That guy has just been publicly ridiculed and humiliated by Thorin.

Anything I have missed?

Comment: If I remember the movie right, the people displayed quite a dislike for the dwarfs (they were ready to lynch them or something). They only cheered Thorin after (and because) he promised them gold and riches. But, Kili & co. weren't part of the group that would bring them anything, so I assume that the dislike stayed.

Comment: @VedranŠego Yes, they weren't part of the group at that time. But surely it would put the citizens of Esgaroth in a bad position for demanding their share if Kili succumbs to his wound and Thorin gets to know that his nephew died due to refusal of medical assistance?

Comment: They didn't seem to be planning that far ahead. But I do agree that my explanation is weak; that's why I didn't offer it as an answer.

Comment: @VedranŠego You still have a point there I think. They definitely aren't portrayed as particularly smart or forward-thinking (with the exception of Bard).

Comment: Yes, Bard is very different from them all. I'd like to hear from someone who read the book: is this part of the story Tolkien's or Jackson's? If it's the former, then I'd expect a better explanation than mine; otherwise, not so much.

Comment: @VedranŠego The whole plot line with Kili's wound, Thorin leaving him behind and the attack on Bard's home does not occur in the book. As for the people of Esgaroth, there are some passages which suggest a certain fickleness and disregard to repercussions (IIRC).

Comment: Thank you. In this case, I don't expect any deeper explanation. Personally, I consider The Hobbit movies to be a big disappointment compared to LOTR trilogy, and this would be just another "detail" making it so.

Comment: Another question.. How come they didn't wait/wake up for Bofur when leaving on the boat?

Answer (score 2):

Kili's  wound was used to promote the relationship between him and Tauriel. As pointed out before it doesn't occur in the book. The people of Esgaroth, basically having been robbed blind by the "master", are naturally mistrustful of just about anyone. I would say they went to Bard, because he had aided them before and felt they could trust him. Plus they really had no place else to turn.